# How to use the in-place version of cholfact() in Julia?

Tags: linear-algebra, julia

I need to solve **A**x = b, where **A** is a symmetric positiv semi-definite matrix. This can be efficiently implemented using the cholesky decomposition. Because the matrix **A** will be at least have the dimensions 25000 x 25000, I cannot waste memory. Therefore I want to use the in-place version of Julia's cholfact:

```
cholfact!(A, :U, pivot = true)
```

Compared to

```
F = cholfact(A, :U, pivot = true)
```

this would save Gigabytes of memory.

However after the computation, `A` is of the type `Matrix Float64`, while `F` has the type `CholeskyPivoted{Float64}`. I far as I understand the in-place version loses essential information, such as the pivot vector `F.piv`. How can I compute the cholesky decomposition correctly whithout wasting memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to combine these two:

```
F = cholfact!(A, :U, pivot = true)
```

This returns a `CholeskyPivoted`, which is indeed what you want. But by using `cholfact!`, you're saying that you don't care whether `A` gets destroyed in the process. Consequently, it will use the memory allocated for `A` for storing the factorization (thus destroying `A`).

Afterwards, you should only use `F`, not `A`, because `A` has been destroyed. Internally, `F` will contain a reference to `A`, since it's storing the factorization in `A`. This may be clearer if you examine how a [`CholeskyPivoted` is represented](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/bdd459796568950f28be33c65be95bb9961c5a66/base/linalg/factorization.jl#L20-L27); `A` will be used for that `UL` field.

Comment: why does this not work for me?
ERROR: unrecognized keyword argument "pivot"
 in cholfact! at linalg/cholesky.jl:101